# Scala Parent Class like Parent class in java i,e Java.lang.Object

Tags: java, scala

Is **`java.lang.Object`** the parent class of all **Scala** `classes`, or any other. I had searched on Google but didn't get appropriate result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

resueman's answer isn't correct. It's true that `Any` is the ancestor of all Scala classes, but isn't the same as `Object`; [`AnyRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyRef) is. `Any` is the parent of `AnyRef` and `AnyVal`, which is the ancestor of *value types*: both ones which correspond to JVM primitives like `Int`, `Boolean`, etc. but are still considered classes in Scala type system, and user-defined [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/value-classes.html). You can see the Scala class hierarchy (before value classes and universal traits were introduced) below (image from http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is no. Any is the root of the Scala class hierarchy**

Taken from the docs:
    Class Any is the root of the Scala class hierarchy. 
    Every class in a Scala execution environment inherits directly or indirectly from this class.

The answer is not so easy as Scala is may seem on the first glance: 
Scala is not always compiled to the JVM, 
there for example is ScalaJs. (http://www.scala-js.org/)

Here for example `Object` is not java.lang.Object but http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/0.5.2/index.html#scala.scalajs.js.Object$.

If Scala is compiled to the JVM `Any` equals to `Object`
but if you compile Scala to a different execution environment this relation may not be stable.